# Mapbox GL JA - labels don't appear

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have several layers.  One of the last layers to load is a layer to add labels to lines as follows;

```
    /** addLayer aa_piste_name **/
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'aa_piste_name',
        'type': 'symbol',  // background, fill, line, symbol, raster, circle, fill-extrusion, heatmap, hillshade, sky.
        'source': 'aa_piste',
        'source-layer': aa_pistes_source_layer ,
         'layout': {
            "text-field": "{id}",
            "symbol-placement": "line",
            //"text-font": ["Roboto Condensed Italic"],
            "text-size": 25,
            "text-justify": "center",
            "symbol-spacing": 1000,
            "text-anchor": "center",
            "text-allow-overlap": true
          },

    });
```

There are a few problems and I am not sure where to start reading:

1. The label is only viewable, and only slightly, at a certain zoom level ( It disappears if I zoom out or in.)
2. It is very very faint.  You can see the end of the label, "...59" just a bit (see below).

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?